# jQuery getJSON - error with URL, please HELP

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm a beginner in jQuery, and I tried to use the getJSON, but I always have an error when using it with an URL, whereas it worked when I used it with a text file.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with the URL ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://localhost/edoc?appname=eDRITS&prgname=JSON2",function(item){
     alert("success");
    $.each(item.users, function(i,user){
        content = '<p>' + user.name + ', ' + user.fname + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#list");
    });
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); });
});
</script>
```

The URL in the code is the call to a program which returns JSON data :

> {"users":[ {"usrid":"GABR90","name":"ABRAMOVA ","fname":"Galina "}] }

If I replace the URL by a text file which contains the JSON data, it works :

```
$.getJSON("file.txt",function(item){...}
```

The error I get with the URL is just the display of my ".error() function", I dont have any specific error message, and I don't know how to use debugger to see the HTTP Get of the browser (which is Firefox).

So how can I use it with the URL, please ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Are you accessing the HTML page using file:/// and then have that page call http://localhost ? If that is the case, then you are hitting the "same origin" limitation.

Your browser see the page as coming from a file:// url, and when that page tries to connect to http://localhost, that is technically another domain, and for security reasons the browser may (and usually will) block that communication. When you instead point to a text file, it see both the html and the file coming from file:// and will allow the communication.

You should load the HTML page in your web server, so that you can access the page using a http://localhost/mypage.html or similar url.

Comment: Hi Simone, yes indeed I use file:// to access the HTML file. How can I load the page to the browser ?

Comment: Follow this check list : 1) are you sure the URL http://localhost/edoc?appname=eDRITS&prgname=JSON2 is actually returning the JSON you are expecting? 2) Follow genesis suggestion to have more informations about the error message 3) Install firebug for Firefox, so that you can see what it's happening and if there is some other strange error.

Comment: 1) yes, the URL returns the JSON data (that I copied to a text file to test with text file). 2) with Genesys suggestion, I got this error "[object Object] error undefined.". 3)I have installed Firebug, can you tell me what to look into ? Thanks